# VBA issues with sending SMS

Tags: excel, vba, api, sms

I have a code for my Excel application. It generates a product invoice and every time the invoice generated it will send the current billed amount along with thanks message. I have purchased a bulk SMS account and they have provided me the API.

**I am using the "ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink" method to send SMS, but it is sending SMS 2 times. Can anyone tell me why this method sends sms 2 times??**

I have written the following program:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim murl As String

murl = "<< SMS API HERE >>"

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=murl

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you actually calling `Macro1()` ? and have you tried stepping through using F8 to see if it's actually being hit twice, have you tried calling the same API method another way to make sure the duplication is not on the site side?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything. I also tried stepping through using F8 it's actually hit single. I have noticed that it will send SMS while the browser is loading and 2nd msg after the browser successfully loaded.

Comment: I'd recommend using an `MSXML2.ServerHTTP60` object to send a get request to the URL rather than opening a browser. I'll post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a raw GET request to your API, here is an example using late-binding to send a GET request to a google page - the `MsgBox` line is simply showing the response from google and you can replace the google.co.uk URL with your own API URL.

```
Public Sub Send_GET()
    Dim con As Object ' MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Set con = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") ' New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    con.Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.uk", False
    con.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    con.send
    MsgBox con.responsetext
End Sub
```

I've used late binding but if you want to explore the proper objects and properties then add a reference to "Microsoft XML v6.0" in your VBA project and you can get rid of the `Object` and `CreateObject` parts - sending requests like this is SO USEFUL.

Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it helps solve your problem.